# getArguments() always returns null

Tags: android

Basically I have a weird problem here ,

In the list item click fucntion:

```
sDialogClickedAtPosition = position;
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
Notes_Taking_Dialog Dialog = new Notes_Taking_Dialog();
Dialog.setTargetFragment(Notes_List_fragment.this, REQUESTCODE_FORDIALOG);

if(!(mDescriptionOfNote.get(sDialogClickedAtPosition).toString().equals
        ("Note #" + sDialogClickedAtPosition)))
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(BUNDLE_TO_DIALOG
            , mDescriptionOfNote.get(sDialogClickedAtPosition));
    Dialog.setArguments(args);
}
Dialog.show(fm, CallingNotesDialogTAG);
```

in the if when I check if the note was modified and saved before so I can pass it and display it in the note dialog , it works fine no crash or anything

in the oncreateDialog in the dialog class when I do this:

```
if(getArguments().getString(Note_taking.BUNDLE_TO_DIALOG).toString() != null)
```

in crashes here in the if statement , weather I use to string or not it's the same , what am I doing wrong ?

when I delete the if statement everything works just fine except I can't display that note that was saved before since if I tried to it'll crash...

to make everything clear the note is in the mDescriptionOfNote.get(position) mDescriptionOfNote is an array list with type string.

---

//EDIT1:

the logcat it shows a null pointer exception at:

java.lang.NullPointerException
Notes_Taking_Dialog.onCreateDialog(Notes_Taking_Dialog.java:63)

which points to the if statement here

//Edit2:

I've fixed it finally :D

the problem was in the if statement in the onListItemClick , I was saving the note and checking if a new list is created and clicked then I don't want to pass the data to the dialog since the data it would be string "Note #" + position , I only wanted to pass notes that was saved before like " android " it's allowed to be passed and displayed in the note , so when I create a new list and click it it won't pass anything , so in the dialog the getArguments().getString() it'll return null since there's nothing there ,

so I fixed it by passing null or "" when the first if does not start.

Thanks all of you and sorry for wasting your time..

Comment: Read and/or post the logcat

Comment: It shows a null pointer exception at the if line , when I delete it and run it again it works just fine...

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect *what* is `null` at that line

Comment: @codeMagic , I'm sorry but I've never used breakpoints but isn't the point is to find which line is causing the crash ? I already know which line , it's the if statement or anywhere when I use getArguments().getString(Note_taking.BUNDLE_TO_DIALOG) , when I delete this line everything works like a charm.

Comment: If you're getting a `String`... why are you calling `toString()` on the `String`?

Comment: @hichris123 because I've tried a lot of ways to fix it nothing works , so no harm on trying this :D

Comment: Yes, you need to find the line first but then you need to find which object in that line is `null`. [See here about breakpoints in Eclipse](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FEclipseDebugging%2Farticle.html&ei=aUTQU9W-Ls-LyASxn4GoDQ&usg=AFQjCNF1P6BWwCyTU233dk2PWcpqdSDR-w&sig2=_UN-Cc4ZnMDWqW--WIMGaA&bvm=bv.71667212,d.aWw)

Comment: Seems like `getArguments()` is returning null. Make sure you are going  into the `if` statement where you set up the arguments, maybe your code is always skipping that part?